# plot a vector function

Tags: functions, vectors

Sketch the $ v = \frac {r} {r ^ 2}$ vector function and calculate its divergent.  How do you plot a vector function?

Comment: A mathematical function that outputs a vector is known as a vector function. To graph a vector function, first make a data table of the x and y values that the function outputs for several input values. Then, plot these points on a coordinate graph. Now you have a graph of a vector function!

Comment: @TranTu Do you know any software that does this?

Comment: I would also like to know a good one for this

Comment: @Hermes I can't find any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The divergence of $\vec{v} = \frac{\hat{r}}{r^{2}}$ is easier to compute using spherical coordinates. Because $\vec{v}$ does not depend on $\theta, \phi$, its divergent is simply 
$$\nabla \cdot \vec{v} = \frac{1}{r^{2}}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg{(}r^{2}\frac{1}{r^{2}}\bigg{)} = 0$$